# When attempting to create a new instance it's losing the associated parameter required to do so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

Rails 5.1.6

I've got an app where products are listed and you can add a quantity of a product to an order. Well, that's the idea anyway. So, right now I've got a form to grab the quantity and also grab the product id and the order id to associate them through the order_items table which also holds the quantity. It looks like the form is grabbing the order_id and setting it in the order_items parameter. In this case, 5. Order with id 5 does exist in the db. When the params are passed to .new however, it's passing a blank id? What am I missing here?

> > ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order with 'id'=): < wha?where'd the id go?

Form ERB

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="col s4">

  <h4><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %></h4>

  <%= form_for @order_item do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :order_id, value: @order.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, placeholder: "quantity" %>

    <span class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><%= f.submit "Add to order" %></span>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController

```
  def create
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @item = @order.order_items.new(item_params)
    @order.save
    if @order.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your order has been added!"
      redirect_to orders_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

 def item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :order_id)
 end
```

Terminal

```
Started POST "/order_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-06 16:50:31 -0700
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_item"=>{"order_id"=>"5", 
"product_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add to order"}
Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE 
"orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order with 'id'=):

app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three things wrong with your :create action:

1) One of the hidden fields in your form passes the order_id in as a param, you should use that to find the order like so:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:order_item][:order_id])
```

2) You call save twice on the `@order` instance in the :create action.

3) You are actually calling save on the `@order` instance variable, but at no point do you save the `@item` instance variable. Is `@item` saved when `@order` is saved?

So I'd try the following:

```
def create
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_item][:order_id])

  # how come you don't save this? You instantiate it but don't appear to call save at any point.
  @item = @order.order_items.new(item_params)

  # remove the following line, which I've commented out:
  # @order.save

  # Consider whether you wish to save @order or @item, or both
  if @order.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your order has been added!"
    redirect_to orders_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
```

You're finding by `params[:id]`. But look!

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_item"=>{"order_id"=>"5", "product_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add to order"}
```

No `params[:id]`. You do, however, have `params[:order_item][:order_id]`. Perhaps you intended to use that?

Also, you can simplify your `create` action:

```
def create
  @order_item = OrderItem.new(item_params)
  if @order_item.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your order has been added!"
    redirect_to orders_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Given that you have all the `order_item` attributes in your parameters:

```
"order_item"=>{"order_id"=>"5", "product_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>""}
```

There's no real need to find `@order` (unless you're feeling all belt and suspenders about things).